# Concatenate returned strings into a single line python without using end=" "

Tags: python-3.x

```
#open a file for input
#loop through the contents to find four letter words
#split the contents of the string
#if length of string = 4 then print the word
my_file = open("myfile.txt", 'r')
for sentence in my_file:
    single_strings = sentence.split()
    for word in single_strings:
       if len(word) == 4:
          print(word)
```

I would like my code to return four letter words in a single string and instead it returns each string on a new line. How can I return the strings as one string so that I can split() them and get their length to print out.

Comment: Your code doesn't return anything, it prints things. That may be a good start. Put things in a function and make it return values. Then outside of this function print things.

Comment: ```#open a file for input
#loop through the contents to find four letter words
#split the contents of the string
#if length of string = 4 then return the word
my_file = open("tiiso.txt", 'r')
def four_letter_word():
    for sentence in my_file:
        single_strings = sentence.split()
        for word in single_strings:
            if len(word) == 4:
               return word
print(four_letter_word())```

Comment: @cglacet I have put my code in a function and to my surprise it no longer prints 5 strings on different lines but 1 string

Answer (score 1):

All problems are simpler when broke in small parts. First write a function that return an array containing all words from a file:

```py
def words_in_file(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    return [word for sentence in f for word in sentence.split()]
```

Then a function that filters arrays of words:

```py
def words_with_k_letters(words, k=-1):
  return filter(lambda w: len(w) == k, words)
```

Once you have these two function the problem becomes trivial:

```py
words = words_in_file("myfile.txt")
words = words_with_k_letters(words, k=4)
print(', '.join(words))
```

Comment: Thank you @cglacet for the solution. I am new to Python programming and prgramming in general. That was how far I can break down the problem with my little understanding. I look forward to learning a lot from the community and of course yourself included sir.